# Cambiar nombre de archivo a final de mes y crear otro

Tags: windows, vbscript

Estoy realizando un programa que cuando ejecutas una función acaba guardando los datos en un archivo csv. Como ese archivo csv contiene solamente los resultados del mes, para evitar que se solapen y puedan dar problemas he decidido separar los archivos por meses.

Estoy buscando un script que lo haga, y se pueda programar para hacerlo automáticamente al final de cada mes. De momento esto es lo que tengo, pero no me reconoce la última línea de código y no lo copia. Sé que aun no está preparado para ejecutarse mensualmente, eso lo prepararé una vez que el script funcione.

```
Dim OldFile, FSO, objFile
Set FSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

OldFile = "C:\Users\lad2tr\Desktop\Results.csv"

Set objFile = FSO.GetFile(OldFile)
objFile.Name = "Results1.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

Dim objFSO, objFile

Dim FileOld, FileNew

Set objFSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

FileOld = "D:\files\archivo.csv"

If Day(Date) = Day(DateSerial(Year(Date), Month(Date) + 1, 1 - 1))Then

```
If (objFSO.FileExists(FileOld)) Then
    Dim AnoMes
    AnoMes = Year(Date) & Right("00" & Month(Date), 2)

    FileNew = "D:\files\archivo_" & AnoMes & ".csv"

    objFSO.CopyFile FileOld, FileNew, true
End If
```

End If

Tal vez es lo que necesites